# Верно расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Верно расставлены знаки препинания?
1. "Похоже, это землетрясение завалило ручей камнями. Надо разобрать их. Жаль, рядом нет Тэда - он любит возиться с камнями."
2. «Если использовать тонкие и гибкие прутья, получится прочная сетка. Ещё пару витков, узел здесь, закрепить здесь — и готово!»
3. «Нужно принести побольше дров, пока в джунглях не так страшно, и зажечь маяк.»
4. "Может, его плохо видно с моря и стоит класть побольше дров?"

Comment: Верно - как вариант.

Comment: Что значит, как вариант? Какой, чего вариант?

Comment: SancheZ, во многих случаях есть несколько вариантов расстановки знаков препинания, и все они верные.

Comment: Т.е. здесь написано всё верно? А в предложении "Жаль, рядом нет Тэда - он любит возиться с камнями." может надо двоеточие поставить, вместо тире? Вторая часть дополняет первую и можно поставить потому что...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. "Похоже, это землетрясение завалило ручей камнями. Надо разобрать их. Жаль, рядом нет Тэда - он любит возиться с камнями."
> 2. «Если использовать тонкие и гибкие прутья, получится прочная сетка. Ещё пару витков, узел здесь, закрепить здесь — и готово!»
> 3. «Нужно принести побольше дров, пока в джунглях не так страшно, и зажечь маяк.»
> 4. "Может, его плохо видно с моря и стоит класть побольше дров?"

Специально цитирую, чтобы кто-нибудь не поправил в вопросе.

Первое, что бросается в глаза: точка внутри кавычек. Никогда и ни за что. (Внутри скобок - отдельная тема.)

1. *«Похоже, это землетрясение завалило ручей камнями. Надо разобрать их. Жаль, рядом нет Тэда — он любит возиться с камнями».*
2. *«Если использовать тонкие и гибкие прутья, получится прочная сетка. Ещё пару витков, узел здесь, закрепить здесь — и готово!»*
3. *«Нужно принести побольше дров, пока в джунглях не так страшно, и зажечь маяк».*
4. *«Может, его плохо видно с моря и стоит класть побольше дров?»*

Здесь всё, ни одного добавочного знака!

---

Всегда остаётся проблемный знак - точка за закрывающей кавычкой, которой предшествует вопросительный или восклицательный знак. Корректоры и редакторы её не любят, скидывают, ссылаясь на примеры из классики, на более ранние (с лучшей полиграфической подготовкой) издания. Но можно найти правила, где её предписывают ставить при расширенном контексте - закавыченному предложению предшествуют авторские слова с повествовательной интонацией.

Answer (score 2):

> А в предложении "Жаль, рядом нет Тэда - он любит возиться с камнями." может надо двоеточие поставить, вместо тире? Вторая часть дополняет первую и можно поставить потому что... – SancheZ 20 часов назад

По строгим правилам требуется двоеточие, на практике многие ставят тире. Вот что пишет Лопатин ([Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135)):

> Примечание 2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). Вот, в частности, примеры из произведений К. Паустовского: Изредка в небе светилось голубоватое пятно — за тучками пробивалась луна, но тотчас гасла; Подснежники, наверное, уже прорастали в земле — их слабый травянистый запах просачивался сквозь снег; Слой облаков был очень тонок — сквозь него просвечивало солнце; На молу погасили огни — теплоход ушел; Татьяна Андреевна вздрагивала от сырости — после теплой каюты на палубе было свежо; Паханов крепко держал капитана за локоть — капитан был еще слаб после ранения; Ей хотелось заплакать — лом даже через варежки леденил руки; В армию меня тоже не берут — сердце заштопанное; Однажды зимой вышел я и слышу — стонет кто-то за оградой.
>
> Примеры из произведений современных авторов и из периодической печати: Думать мне пришлось недолго — дверь распахнулась, и я увидел Чапаева (Пелев.); В дом попасть никто не мог — двери и окна были закрыты (газ.); Доски гнулись и ходили ходуном под его ботинками — он был тяжелым, а пол старым (Уст.); Мы ее Барбариска звали — она вечно всех детей карамелью угощала... (Улиц.). То же при глаголах, требующих пояснения: Вскинул голову — у порога стоит Мария (Шукш.); А помню — в сугробах тонули дворы (Сн.); Казалось мне — с любовью строгой она глядит из-под бровей (Лис); Она испуганно осмотрелась — никого (Расп.); Ольга посмотрела вперед — ничего особенного.. .(Уст.).

Comment: Спасибо, вас понял.